# Android marshmallow listview scrolling gets blurry

Tags: android, listview, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have an android application which is running on production for several years. Lately, I have discovered a problem with a ListView in the app, that gets blurry while scrolling. The problem only occurs under Android **Marshmallow**.

[Here is a screenshot of the ListView while scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHDPs.png)

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What type of phone or emulator are you testing on? Post your adapter code.

Comment: Are you setting window background to null?

Comment: Not sure, how do I do that? Thanks.

Comment: I am having the same issue as well (Marshmallow only).  My window background is not `null`.  Did you happen to stumble across a fix yet?

Comment: @pathfinderelite - no, not yet..

Comment: @Moshe Ventura :can you just link this application so that I can test it on my marshmallow device?

Answer (score 1):

**Preface**: I posted a separate answer prior to this one, but that solution only worked on my MotoX.  I later discovered it did not work for my Galaxy Tab A.  The answer here seems to be more universal:

I was able to fix my scrolling blur by defining a separate ListView style for my application and specifying a different list divider.  So, for my application theme I set this:

```
<item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/ListViewStyleNoBlur</item>
```

Where `ListViewStyleNoBlur` is defined as:

```
<style name="ListViewStyleNoBlur" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView.White">
    <item name="android:divider">@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright</item>
</style>
```

I specified these in a `values-v23` resources folder so the change doesn't affect pre-Marshmallow devices.

My application theme is based off of `android:style/Theme.Light`, which is why my list view style's parent is `android:style/Widget.ListView.White`.  My app min SDK is 8, which is why I'm using such an "old" theme.  I also noticed that if I use a "newer" theme, such as Holo, the blur does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and, through trial-and-error, finally found a solution.  Hopefully it will also work for you.  This appears to be a bug in Marshmallow related to the scroll bar in list views.  I had the following property set in my application theme, and removing this property fixed the blurry scrolling:

```
<item name="android:fadeScrollbars">false</item>
```

Using `true` instead of `false` also works, but is unnecessary since it is the default.  I also discovered (through trail-and-error) that using `android:fastScrollEnabled="true"` causes the same blurring, but based on your scrollbar style, you do not appear to be using it.

In summary, don't use `android:fadeScrollbars`.  If that doesn't fix your issue, try playing around with any other scrollbar-related styles you may be using on your ListView, bearing in mind these styles may be part of the view directly, or part of an activity or application theme.